# Set "home webpage" on C# Browser

Tags: c#, browser, launcher

I am working on a video game launching program, and would like to include a browser that shows my game's home page. I want it to be in the program, to force them to see it.

So, I placed a web browser control, however, I want to force them to see a page when they start the program.

How can I set the "home page" of the browser without editing the rest of their computer's settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the `WebBrowser` control, then use the [`Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352.aspx) method.